# Ubuntu 18.04.1 hangs regularly

Tags: nginx, ufw, ubuntu-18.04

I have some Ubuntu 18.04.1 virtual machines installed on VMWare ESXi 6.5, all of them have 3 core, 3GB ram, attached to a SAS Storage array.

The servers are running `nginx 1.14.0` as reverse proxy for 3-5 vhosts. `ufw` is enabled to allow SSH from LAN IP's and http/https from the rest.

When I turn off `ufw`, The server randomly has one core on 100%, and becomes unresponsive on the console, but also does not respond on web-requests anymore. This also happens sometimes when `ufw` is enabled, but way less often.

What could happen that the server does this? And how to avoid it from happening again ?

[image: VMWare ESXi monitoring on CPU]

Output of `iptables-save`

https://pastebin.com/TM8nsapJ

Answer (score 3):

The issue appeared to be a known bug with `VMWare ESXi 6.5.0` in combination with the `VMXNET3` driver.

Following [VMWare KB2151480](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2151480) resolved the issue.

Comment: nice. glad you got it sorted :)

Answer (score 0):

What procs are using the most cpu during this time? Are you seeing anything in syslog or dmesg during this time? One thing you might try is installing atop, and then walking back through the atop logs after this happens to see what processes are eating up cpu. What does the network traffic look like in the vsphere web client for these vm's right before they go unresponsive? This could be a syn-flood or something similar, but ufw could also be a red herring here.

Comment: All logging is empty during the period that the system hangs, syslog has no lines for 5 minutes. Network traffic is zero, disk usage also zero. I can't access dmesg from before the reboot because nothing responds anymore. I can trigger the hanging however by scanning the site via ssllabs.com

Comment: hmm... `ufw` is actually just a wrapper for iptables. can you show the output of `iptables-save` ? Also if you if you stop nginx, does the hanging go away completely?

Comment: I catched a message on the console, which shows it's a `kernel BUG` in the vmxnet3 driver. Found a work-around on VMWare website, will try that first